# 3 dimensional array as input for Keras

Tags: python, keras, artificial-intelligence

I got a 3 dimensional array and would like to use it as an input for a sequential model in Keras. The shape of the input array is (32, 32, 4). I want to get an array with the same shape as output. How should i make a feed forward neuronal network with one input, one output and one hidden layer, to make it work with such an array as input?

Comment: Is there something that you've tried already that isn't working? In particular, do you know how you might do this with a 2D input?

Comment: Can you share the code you've written so far and highlight where you are getting errors?